# Слайдер fotorama не отображает alt

Tags: javascript, css

При использовании fotorama, не отображаются alt в картинках.
Прошу помощи.

Вот мой thml :

```
<div class="section-gallery fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-thumbwidth="110.5" data-thumbheight="66" data-thumbborderwidth="5" data-thumbmargin="13" data-width="100%">                        
    <img src="img/3.1.jpg" alt="галерея салона">
    <img src="img/3.2.jpg" alt="галерея салона">
    <img src="img/3.5.jpg" alt="галерея салона">
    <img src="img/3.6.jpg" alt="галерея салона">
    <img src="img/3.jpg"   alt="галерея салона">
    <img src="img/3.5.jpg" alt="галерея салона">
</div>
```

После подключения fotorama пропадают как я писал выше атрибут alt:

```
<img src="img/3.1.jpg" class="fotorama_img" style="width: 381.292px; height: 254px; left: 0.354023px; top: 0px;">
```

Ну и естественно google page speed просто орет в ответ, что картинки без alt.

Comment: Ты код-то добавь. Может какой-то знак препинания пропустил.

Comment: Нам догадаться нужно, где у Вас может быть ошибка? Прикрепите к вопросу Ваш код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это баг fotorama, с которым вам придётся смириться. https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/329